# Getting the closest item with specified ID after tr

Tags: jquery, selection, closest

I'm using this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next()
```

To select a `table row`, but I also need to select a tr with specified id after this tr.

I've tried like to do it this way:

```
var a = $(this).closest('tr').next()
var b = $(a).closest('#itemrow').next()
```

`var a` is working fine, but it does not select an `var b`.

What it the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('#itemrow:first')
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess if u do this it will work fine

```
var a = $(this).closest('tr').next()
var b = a.closest('#itemrow').next()
```

a is already a jquery object dont surround it with $()